# Running an Excel macro when info is pushed through a DDE connection

Tags: excel, vba, dde

I currently have an HMI that communicates with Excel through a DDE connection. 
If I update values in the HMI then the values are updated in the spreadsheet of Excel and vice versa. Which is exactly what I want. However, I created a VBA code that will also update values in the spreadsheet when values are changed in the HMI. This VBA code does not run though if I change the values through the HMI but will run if I manually change them in Excel. 
Is there something that I am not considering?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("K1:K3"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call UpdateDateandTime
    End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateDateandTime()
    MsgBox "yes"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you made the link with a function, such as [RTD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/set-up-realtimedata-function), then correct, Worksheet_Change does not fire when cell functions recalculate.

Comment: `Range(Target.Address)` makes no sense. Just `Target` will do fine. Otherwise you could write `Range(Range(Target.Address).Address)` and so on

Answer (score 0):

as a crude workaround, If only three cells are involved, may create some simple formula in other cells involving the target cells (if not already exists) and use `Worksheet_Calculate()` event do the processing. Something like,

```
Public VarK1, VarK2, Vark3
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If VarK1 <> Range("K1").Value Or VarK2 <> Range("K2").Value Or Vark3 <> Range("K3").Value Then
    VarK1 = Range("K1").Value
    VarK2 = Range("K2").Value
    Vark3 = Range("K3").Value
   'Call the required process
End If
End Sub
```

though other direct methods involving DDE may be also be available to do the same and may please research/wait further for more appropriate the commands. Another workaround way is  to use [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) method.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome, you made my day